# Visual Studio 2017 instance is not opened

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Can anyone have any idea why Visual studio instance is not getting opened and how can I fix that. Below is error details I found from Visual Studio logs & system.

- Visual Studio 2017 (15.9.22)
- .Net Framework : 4.7 OS
- Windows Server 2016

**MSVCP120_CLR0400.dll is either not designed to run on Windows**

> C:\Windows\system32\MSVCP120_CLR0400.dll is either not designed to run
>   on Windows or it contains an error. Try installing the program again
>   using the original installation media or contact your system
>   administrator or the software vendor for support. Error status
>   0xc000012f.

**The type initializer for '' threw an exception.**

> LegacySitePackage failed for package [Environment Package Window
>   Management]Source: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0' Description:
>   The type initializer for '' threw an exception.
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   '' threw an exception. --->
>   .ModuleLoadException: The C++ module failed
>   to load during appdomain initialization. --->
>   System.DllNotFoundException:
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF\wpfgfx_v0400.dll
>   ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: %1 is not a valid Win32 application --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   MS.Internal.NativeWPFDLLLoader.LoadNativeWPFDLL(UInt16* relDllPath,
>   UInt16* baseDllPath) at
>   MS.Internal.NativeWPFDLLLoader.LoadCommonDLLsAndDwrite() at
>   CModuleInitialize.{ctor}(CModuleInitialize* , IntPtr cleaningUpFunc)
>   at ?A0x4260310d.CreateCModuleInitialize() at
>   ?A0x4260310d.??__E?A0x4260310d@cmiStartupRunner@@YMXXZ() at
>   _initterm_m((fnptr)* pfbegin, (fnptr)* pfend) at .LanguageSupport.InitializePerAppDomain(LanguageSupport*
>   ) at
>   .LanguageSupport._Initialize(LanguageSupport*
>   ) at
>   .LanguageSupport.Initialize(LanguageSupport*
>   ) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   .LanguageSupport.Initialize(LanguageSupport*
>   ) at .cctor() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ThreadHelper.get_DispatcherForUIThread()
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ThreadHelper.CheckAccess() at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.AsyncPackage.GetService(Type serviceType)
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Initialize() at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.AsyncPackage.Initialize() at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackage.SetSite(IServiceProvider
>   sp).ModuleLoadException: The C++ module
>   failed to load during appdomain initialization. --->
>   System.DllNotFoundException:
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF\wpfgfx_v0400.dll
>   ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: %1 is not a valid Win32 application --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   MS.Internal.NativeWPFDLLLoader.LoadNativeWPFDLL(UInt16* relDllPath,
>   UInt16* baseDllPath) at
>   MS.Internal.NativeWPFDLLLoader.LoadCommonDLLsAndDwrite() at
>   CModuleInitialize.{ctor}(CModuleInitialize* , IntPtr cleaningUpFunc)
>   at ?A0x4260310d.CreateCModuleInitialize() at
>   ?A0x4260310d.??__E?A0x4260310d@cmiStartupRunner@@YMXXZ() at
>   _initterm_m((fnptr)* pfbegin, (fnptr)* pfend) at .LanguageSupport.InitializePerAppDomain(LanguageSupport*
>   ) at
>   .LanguageSupport._Initialize(LanguageSupport*
>   ) at
>   .LanguageSupport.Initialize(LanguageSupport*
>   ) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   .LanguageSupport.Initialize(LanguageSupport*
>   ) at .cctor()System.DllNotFoundException:
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF\wpfgfx_v0400.dll
>   ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: %1 is not a valid Win32 application --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   MS.Internal.NativeWPFDLLLoader.LoadNativeWPFDLL(UInt16* relDllPath,
>   UInt16* baseDllPath) at
>   MS.Internal.NativeWPFDLLLoader.LoadCommonDLLsAndDwrite() at
>   CModuleInitialize.{ctor}(CModuleInitialize* , IntPtr cleaningUpFunc)
>   at ?A0x4260310d.CreateCModuleInitialize() at
>   ?A0x4260310d.??__E?A0x4260310d@cmiStartupRunner@@YMXXZ() at
>   _initterm_m((fnptr)* pfbegin, (fnptr)* pfend) at .LanguageSupport.InitializePerAppDomain(LanguageSupport*
>   ) at
>   .LanguageSupport._Initialize(LanguageSupport*
>   ) at
>   .LanguageSupport.Initialize(LanguageSupport*
>   )System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): %1 is not a valid
>   Win32 application

Comment: because VS is still 32bit application the dll must be 32bit. This file is part of Windows, so repair windows by running [sfc/DISM](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system)

Comment: thank you @magicandre1981 for your help.. I tried same but it did not work for me..

Comment: was DISM able to repair files?

Comment: Some of the files could not be repaired as per DISM and in detail logs I ckecked an found "C:\Windows\system32\MSVCP120_CLR0400.dll " was not repaired

Comment: use [/Source option and point to Windows ISO](https://superuser.com/a/1004976/174557): **Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /source:wim:D:\sources\install.wim:1 /limitaccess**